# Had seen or has seen?

Tags: grammar

Which should I use?

After Tom _______ the movie at the cinema, he decided to buy the book.

Had seen or has seen?

Thanks

Comment: Which do you think you should use? and Why?

Answer (score -2):

Both are technically possible, but using **has** makes the first clause of the sentence present tense and the last clause past tense, which doesn't make much sense. Best, therefore, to go for **had** to make the sentence consistent.

Comment: Welcome to the site @dizzi90. I downvoted your answer because I disagree that 'has seen' is a viable choice. You say that it doesn't make much sense, which is true, and in fact it's grammatically incorrect in a way that doesn't make any sense. A native speaker wouldn't say that. Just so you know how the site works, you can edit your answer and if you let me know I'll change my vote accordingly. Or if you can convince me that your answer is accurate I'll happily change my mind.